# Search/extract text based on multiple styles

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document with blocks of text marked with styles called "Princple" and "BusinessRule".  These blocks of text are scattered throughout the document.  I would like to find and copy these blocks to a separate document in the order in which they appear.  The code I am using is:

```
Dim SelStyle As String
'SelStyle = "Principle"
SelStyle = "BusinessRule"


Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Style = SelStyle
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute

Selection.Copy
Windows("Document1").Activate
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
Selection.TypeParagraph
Windows("mainDoc.docx").Activate
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
```

As you see, this is a manual process: first un-comment the Principle, extract all of those, then comment Princple and uncomment BusinessRule.  Not great.  Is there any way to search for .Style="Principle" or .Style="BusinessRule" so I get them all in sequence?  (And, secondarily, if you have a suggestion for looping through the whole document to do this, I would be additionally grateful.  :-))

Thanks - Bill

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the values in an array?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim SelStyle(1) As String

    SelStyle(0) = "Principle"
    SelStyle(1) = "BusinessRule"

    For i = 0 To 1
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = ""
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Style = SelStyle(i)

        '
        '~~> Rest of your code
        '
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks SR.  There are two problems with that: (1) It won't retain the order of the content (the two styles are used at many points in the document); and (2) this will find exactly 1 block with a "Principle" style then exactly one block with "BusinessRule" style each time it is executed.  There may a three P textblocks follow by two BR textblocks, then a P, then three more BRs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, I changed my approach on this.  Instead of searching for styles, I go through each paragraph in the document and see if the style is "Principle" or "BusinessRule".  If true, then I copy/paste the paragraph.  So not only do I get the "or", but I also get them in order.